# General Basis Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose V is a vector space, $\vec v, \vec w \in V$ and $ \vec v \neq \vec 0, \vec w \neq \vec 0$ I want to prove {$\vec v_1, \vec v_2, ..., \vec v_k$} is linearly independent and $c_1, c_2, ..., c_k \in \mathbb {R}$ with $c_i \neq 0$ for all i, then {$c_1\vec v_1, c_2\vec v_2,..., c_k\vec v_k$} is a basis of <$\vec v_1,\vec v_2,..., \vec v_k$>

To find linear independence I would basically just state that in a linear combination where $c_1\vec v_1+c_2\vec v_2+...+c_k\vec v_k =0$ there would be $c_1,c_2...c_k =0$. Its a basis since its linear independent, but I believe I need to prove it spans V. Could someone point me in the right direction when it comes to proving this?

Comment: where does $\vec w$ come into play?

Comment: It was part of the given information and I decided to state it all. @amWhy

Answer (score -1):

You should be a bit careful with your notation. If $a_1(c_1v_1) + \cdots + a_k(c_kv_k) = 0$ is a linear dependence of the scaled vectors, then $(a_1c_1)v_1 + \cdots + (a_kc_k)v_k = 0,$ so $a_ic_i = 0$ for all $i,$ and since none of the $c_i$ are zero...

Addressing your actual question, you have $k$ linearly independent vectors, so they span a $k$-dimensional subspace of the $k$-dimensional space they live in. How many such subspaces are there?

Comment: I'm guessing k subspaces. I apologize but I'm not following the way you're leading me.

Comment: @KellyR The answer is one. A $k$-dimensional subspace of a $k$-dimensional space can only be the whole thing. So $k$ linearly independent vectors in a $k$-dimensional space always form a basis.

Comment: To prove that the given is a basis am I able to prove it mathematically?

Comment: @KellyR I have done just that. Perhaps you mean that you would like to show directly that any vector in the space can be written as a linear combination of the given vectors? If so, please understand that this is no more "mathematical" an approach.